# How to send a message with discord.py without a command

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

```
import discord
import asyncio

client = discord.Client()
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("I'm ready.")

async def send(message):
    await client.send_message(client.get_channel("123456789"), message)

client.run("token")

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(send("hello"))
```

Hi, i want to make a GUI. When someone put in his name and press "OK" my discord bot should send a message. Basically i thought i call the async by it's name, didn't work. Then i made a event loop. worked with a print(), but the bot doesn't send a message, so i thought it is not ready, when i put wait_until_ready() there it executed nothing, so i thought i have to put the client.run("token") before the event loop, didn't work either.

can you guys help me? :)

Comment: just curious, what gui lib are you using ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The reason your code is not working is because `client.run` is blocking, meaning that nothing after it will execute. This means your `loop` will never be reached.

To get around this, use `client.loop.create_task`.

The github of `discord.py` has an example of a background task, found [here](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/background_task_asyncio.py). You should be able to use this as reference. Currently the task posts a message to the given channel every minute, but you can easily modify it to wait for a specific action.

**New `discord.py` versions**

```
import discord
import asyncio

client = discord.Client()

async def my_background_task():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    counter = 0
    channel = client.get_channel(id=123456789) # replace with channel_id
    while not client.is_closed():
        counter += 1
        await channel.send(counter)
        await asyncio.sleep(60) # task runs every 60 seconds

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')

client.loop.create_task(my_background_task())
client.run('token')
```

**Older `discord.py` versions**

```
import discord
import asyncio

client = discord.Client()

async def my_background_task():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    counter = 0
    channel = discord.Object(id='channel_id_here')
    while not client.is_closed:
        counter += 1
        await client.send_message(channel, counter)
        await asyncio.sleep(60) # task runs every 60 seconds

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')

client.loop.create_task(my_background_task())
client.run('token')
```

Comment: Does this still work? I tried it and it didn't send anything

Comment: @F.M This is outdated as it uses an older version of `discord.py`, referred to as the `async` branch. Things like `client.send_message` don't exist in the newer versions. You need to use `await channel.send()` now. See example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57667461/background-task-py-not-showing-messages-python/57694459#57694459).

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'll check it out

Comment: `*** AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'send_message'`

Comment: @alper `send_message` will only work on older versions of `discord.py`, referred to as the `async` branch. On the new version, you can use `await channel.send(counter)`

Comment: It should also be `channel = client.get_channel(id='channel_id_here')`

Comment: @alper thanks for catching that! Feel free to edit answers if you find other mistakes

Comment: I think also `while not client.is_closed:` should be `while not client.is_closed():` because [it looks like it's a function](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.is_closed)

Comment: I think the correct link to the example is now https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/background_task_asyncio.py the branch you link to/copy-pasted from is really old

Answer (score 1):

For responsive behaviour, you have two options: you can write a `on_message` event handler, or use the `discord.ext.commands` module.  I recommend using `commands`, as it's more powerful and doesn't keep everything in a single coroutine.

```
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

bot = Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("I'm ready.")
    global target_channel
    target_channel = bot.get_channel("412678093006831617")

@bot.command()
async def send(*, message):                         
    global target_channel
    await bot.send_message(channel, message)
```

This would be called with `!send Some message`.  The `*, message` syntax just tells the bot not to try and parse the message contents further.

Comment: Would you be able to call the command from the GUI? Curious as I have not experimented with something like that

Comment: Do you want to send the message from wherever you're running the bot from, or from discord?  I'm not sure what GUI you're talking about.

Comment: LordSquiddy is asking how to make a bot respond after you press OK on a GUI

Comment: @Benjin is right, i would like to send a message when i click OK on a GUI, not from discord.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Log : {client.user}")
    ch = await client.fetch_channel("enter id text channel")
    await ch.send(content="your content")


client.run("token")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but found a better hack to perform this action.
in your bot.py have a global variable for your messages and channel Id if needed

```
channelId = os.getenv('channelId')
token = os.getenv('discordBotToken')
intents = discord.Intents.default()

# inililzing discord client with default intents
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

# Global message variable to be set externally and bot to be triggered
message = ""

# event triggered when the bot is ready
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    channel = client.get_channel(int(channelId)) # find the channel with the channel ID
    await channel.send(message) # send the message from the global variable
    await client.close() # close the client to stop the client blocking code

# method to be executed from an external file
def BotRun():
    client.run(token)
```

Then in your main.py import this file and

```
import bot as discordBot

discordBot.message = "hello!"
discordBot.BotRun()
```

This way u can call this bot without having it running in the background.

The only downside of this as u can expect is that we are closing the client and logging in every time we send a message.