# background_task.py not showing messages - Python

Tags: python, spyder, python-asyncio, discord.py

I noticed that when I ran a code snippet from the discord.py Github page it didn't show the intended message.

My slightly modified code:

```
import discord
import asyncio

import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # create the background task and run it in the background
        self.bg_task = self.loop.create_task(self.my_background_task())

    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged in as')
        print(self.user.name)
        print(self.user.id)
        print('------')

    async def my_background_task(self):
        counter = 0
        channel = self.get_channel(1234567890) # channel ID goes here
        while not self.is_closed():
            counter += 1
            await channel.send(counter)
            await asyncio.sleep(10) # task runs every 10 seconds


client = MyClient()
client.run('token')
```

When I check Discord nothing shows, however it does show output in the IDLE:

```
Logged in as
bot_name
1234567890
------
```

But in the Discord server, nothing happens. Is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: Just checking, but have you replaced `self.get_channel(1234567890)` with the channel ID the message must be sent to?

Comment: I have, but even then it doesn't show anything. I have also replaced the token with the actual one.

Comment: Does the fact that it's being ran on Spyder affect anything? Maybe the nest_asyncio?

Comment: Should I open an issue on the discord.py Github page instead?

Comment: Try running it from command line to see if anything changes. Also make sure you are running the newest version of `discord.py`

Comment: @Benjin It shows the `Logged in as` and such but still doesn't show anything in the Discord server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code fails because `self.get_channel(1234567890)` is used before the bot has properly connected, resulted in it always returning `None`. This is because `client = MyClient()` is done first, meaning the background task is created but the bot has not yet connected, which is done through `client.run`.

To fix this, move the creation of the loop to inside the `on_ready` event.

```
import discord
import asyncio

import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged in as')
        print(self.user.name)
        print(self.user.id)
        print('------')

        # create the background task and run it in the background
        self.bg_task = self.loop.create_task(self.my_background_task())

    async def my_background_task(self):
        counter = 0
        channel = self.get_channel(1234567890) # channel ID goes here
        while not self.is_closed():
            counter += 1
            await channel.send(counter)
            await asyncio.sleep(10) # task runs every 10 seconds


client = MyClient()
client.run('token')
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the bot still does not work. It did exactly what the previous version did. Thank you for your time by the way!

Comment: The above code works. I tested it on my own bot. The only difference is I removed `nest_asyncio` as I do not have it installed.

Comment: This is really strange. I've ran it from command line and it still doesn't seem to work. Could it be a problem with my computer? Nevertheless, I'll accept your answer because my issue seems to be isolated to me.

Comment: Is your bot connected to the server with the channel you want to send messages to? Otherwise, try re-installing Python and/or some of the libraries, such as `discord.py` to see if it fixes the issue.