# send message at a time interval using discord bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I am trying to send message at some time interval using a discord bot . I have found some examples like this one from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57667461/background-task-py-not-showing-messages-python/57694459#57694459) link

```py
import discord
import asyncio

import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged in as')
        print(self.user.name)
        print(self.user.id)
        print('------')

        # create the background task and run it in the background
        self.bg_task = self.loop.create_task(self.my_background_task())

    async def my_background_task(self):
        counter = 0
        channel = self.get_channel(1234567890) # channel ID goes here
        while not self.is_closed():
            counter += 1
            await channel.send(counter)
            await asyncio.sleep(10) # task runs every 10 seconds


client = MyClient()
client.run('token')
```

but when i try to use the same code , I don't get any message in my server . Could anyone help with what I could be doing wrong :|

Comment: Are there any errors? And are you running this in your pc or in google colab or something. If you're running it in a pc. You can remove `nest_asyncio.apply()`.

Comment: No , there are no errors . I am running from https://replit.com/

Comment: I tried debugging . apparently it enters `while not self.is_closed():` but only once . for some reason it does not work after that

Answer (score 0):

You can try using "tasks" (from discord.ext)

```
from discord.ext import tasks

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    send_message.start()

@tasks.loop(seconds=10)  # you can even use hours and minutes
async def send_message():
    await bot.get_channel(id_here).send("message here")
```

If this is not helpful, can you describe about what you are intending to do?