# Any other code doesn't run after I combined discord.py with my main script

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I made a script that includes web scraping and api requests but I wanted to add discord.py for sending the results to my discord server but it stops after this:

```
client.run('token')
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use **threads**.

> Python threading allows you to have different parts of your program run concurrently and can simplify your design.

### What Is a Thread?

A thread is a separate flow of execution. This means that your program will have two things happening at once.

Getting multiple tasks running simultaneously requires a non-standard implementation of Python, writing some of your code in a different language, or using `multiprocessing` which comes with some extra overhead.

### Starting a thread

The Python standard library provides `threading`

```py
import threading
x = threading.Thread(target=thread_function, args=(1,))
x.start()
```

---

### wrapping up

you need to create two threads for each loop. Create and run the discord client in a thread, use another thread for web scraping and API requests.

Answer (score 2):

The `run` method is completely blocking, so there are two ways I can see to solve this issue:

1. create and run the client in a separate thread, and use a queue of some sort to communicate between the client and the rest
2. use the `start` method, that returns an async coroutine which you can wrap into a *task* and multiplex with your scraping and API-requesting, assuming that also uses async coroutines

Answer (score 2):

`client.run` seems to be a blocking operation.
E.g. your code is not meant to be executed after `client.run`

You can try using `loop.create_task()` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49835742/how-to-send-a-message-with-discord-py-without-a-command), to create another coroutine that would run in background and feed some messages into your client.