# Discord Py Running Command from Server

Tags: discord, discord.py

This might be a duplicated question! sorry I couldn't find an answer!

I have a bot running on a linux server "using discord python lib". I want trigger a command from the server side as a cronjob. Is that possible with the way Discord events are designed? The command needs to run every 5 mins!

I have a db with user/payment data. The command should check if the userid has sent payment. If so then assign them a specific role. Otherwise if the user's payment data is false remove the role.

Right now this works fine with a command I wrote "update_payment" however this command has to be triggered from the discord server manually. I don't want to run this by hand every 5 mins. How do I trigger it from a cronjob on the linux server?

Comment: Does it have to run from a cronjob? You can create your own task using `discord.py` that will do this every five minutes. See example of background task [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49835742/how-to-send-a-message-with-discord-py-without-a-command/49836187#49836187).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tasks.loop` to loop your task:

```py
from discord.ext import tasks

@tasks.loop(minutes=5)
async def update_payment():
    pass  # whatever here

update_payment.start()
```

Comment: Can you update your code to show where `tasks.loop` should be used.