# background task only running once discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I've been trying to create a discord bot that finds errors in a certain function and notify you
from discord.ext import commands

```
def alert(message):

    bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

    async def send_hi():
        await bot.wait_until_ready()
        channel = bot.get_channel(942139956938276997)
        await channel.send(message)

    bot.loop.create_task(send_hi())
    bot.run(token)


def error_creator():
    liste = [1, 2, 3, 4, "5", 6]
    s = 0
    for i in liste:
        s = s+i


try:
    error_creator()
except:
    alert("there is an error")

try:
    error_creator()
except:
    alert('stop')
```

the problem is its only reporting the error once although ive called it two times, I can't figure it out

*runnig the bot...*

*there is an error*

and it doesn't continue

Comment: `bot.run` takes control of the program.

Comment: You'll need a loop otherwise your task will only be executed once. See example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49835742/how-to-send-a-message-with-discord-py-without-a-command/49836187#49836187).

Comment: BTW, don't use bare except, only catch what you need, such as `except Exception`.